# facebook facepile generator code is not rendering dark colorscheme

Tags: html, css, facebook

I am using Facebook's code generator here:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/facepile/

If I use "dark" color scheme, it does not work.

Here's the result:
http://chovy.dyndns.org/test/fb.htm

Here's the code generated that does not work:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-facepile" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/google" data-max-rows="3" data-width="400" data-colorscheme="dark"></div>
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for your problem? I am dealing with the same thing right now.

Comment: I don't recall, I'm not responsible for that code anymore.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the instructions: *This script uses the app ID of your app.* You will need to replace the part where it says `&appId=`.

example:

`js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=127593403996233";`